# Why does my FPS drop when I go into maximized windowed mode?

Tags: gaming, fps

When not in Windowed mode my FPS is 50 FPS. As soon as I enter it it drops to 10 FPS. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: My guess would be that it is just using up more resources in maximized window mode. You can try adjusting some of the graphics settings in the game (I'm guessing you're talking about a game) and see if that helps. It might also be that your computer hardware is not able to adequately support full screen at 50 fps.

Comment: I think your question is worded poorly.  Are you trying to say "I get 50 FPS fullscreen, but in windowed mode I get 10?"

Comment: Yes Keltari san

Comment: Check [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/107099) and [this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/107071)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the computer has to render more pixels on your screen. When the window is smaller the computer has to process a smaller image to show you, and vice versa; this puts pressure on hardware.